# Regular Expression Replace a group: varying the output depending upon what it matches

Tags: php, regex

**Regular Expression Replace a group: varying the output depending upon what it matches**

While using [PHP Live Regex - A live Regular Expression Tester for PHP](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

I am unable to get the final group to replace with variable output depending upon what expression is encountered.  I am unsure of how to format the last replacement group so that it does not output the literal value.

I want to do something like this:

```
Regular Expression:
('group1',) (group2,) (group3,) (alpha|beta|charlie)

Replace with:
$1 $2 $3 (1|2|3)
```

And was hoping for a result like this:

```
Example 1:
Source: 'group1', group2, group3, alpha
Result: 'group1', group2, group3, 1

Example 2:
Source: 'group1', group2, group3, beta
Result: 'group1', group2, group3, 2

etc.
```

But, instead I get this:

```
Example 1:
Source: 'group1', group2, group3, alpha
Result: 'group1', group2, group3, (1|2|3)

Example 2:
Source: 'group1', group2, group3, beta
Result: 'group1', group2, group3, (1|2|3)
```

Thanks in advance for help to this issue.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PCRE engine does not support conditional replacement patterns. In PHP, you just need to use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and replace the 4th group with the right value based on the `$matches[4]` (`$m[4]` is used below) value.

See a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/LGjGLU):

```
$string = "'group1', group2, group3, alpha 'group1', group2, group3, beta";
$pattern = "/('group1',) (group2,) (group3,) (alpha|beta|charlie)/i";
$data = array("alpha" => "1", "beta" => "2", "charlie" => "3");
$inc = 0;

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($data) {
        return  $m[1] . " " . $m[2] . " " . $m[3] . " " . $data[$m[4]];
    }, $string);
```

Output: `'group1', group2, group3, 1 'group1', group2, group3, 2`.

Comment: Wiktor, Thank you for the help and the example, this certainly helped me.  Mike